# Compasses and ruler construction of a regular pentagon using $\cos(5\theta)$ identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry

A problem from my algebra homework asks to find a formula for $\cos(5\theta)$ in order to construct the regular pentagon. At first I tried considering $\cos(5\theta) = -1+2\cos^2\left(\frac{5\theta}{2}\right)$ but it seems like I need a degree $5$ polynomial to make this construction work. I'm not sure on how to approach this problem. I feel like I should be making some connection between $\cos(5\theta)$ and $f(x) = x^5-1$ but I'm not sure  how to. I know that $z^5 = |z|^5e^{i5\theta}$, but I don't see how to use this connection for the desired construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use de Moivre's identity
$$(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^5=\cos5\theta+i\sin5\theta$$
and expand the left hand side using binomial expansion, then equate the real components only, you will end up with
$$\cos^5\theta-10\cos^3\theta\sin^2\theta+5\cos\theta\sin^4\theta=\cos5\theta\\\Rightarrow\cos^5\theta-10\cos^3\theta(1-\cos^2\theta)+5\cos\theta(1-\cos^2\theta)^2=\cos5\theta$$
which simplifies to
$$16\cos^5\theta-20\cos^3\theta+5\cos\theta=\cos5\theta$$
To construct the regular pentagon, you need to have $\theta=\frac{2\pi}{5}$, so the equation
$$16\cos^5\theta-20\cos^3\theta+5\cos\theta=1$$
needs to be solved. Setting $\cos\theta=x$, we need to solve $$16x^5-20x^3+5x-1=0$$
multiplying both sides by $2$, and setting $z=2x$, simplifies the equation to the form
$$z^5-5z^3+5z-2=0$$
Note that $z=2$ is a root, so the equation factorises to
$$(z-2)(z^4+2z^3-z^2-2z+1)=0$$
Quite conveniently, $(z^4+2z^3-z^2-2z+1)=(z^2+z-1)^2$, so that we need only to solve for a quadratic.

So that the roots are $z=2$, (repeated roots) $z=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, $z=\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Comment: I see... but once we have the roots (and implicitly the angle $\theta $) how can we construct the pentagon? The problem seems to be asking for a constructive procedure.

Comment: Ideally, your book talks about constructing the rationals, and square roots...

Comment: @KevinSheng Once we have found the roots, hence the cosine of the angle, we can use the method http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon#Using_trigonometry_and_the_Pythagorean_Theorem